# Display numeric column in exponent while keeping the filter function in HTML Rmarkdown DT datatable

Tags: html, r, datatables, r-markdown, dt

I have the following data frame:

```r
df <- data.frame(col1 = letters[1:10],
                 col2 = c(0, 0.52, 0.93, 2, 10, 51, 523, 52353, 623464, 12356833538))
```

I want to display the dataframe with the `DT` package in an HTML R markdown file, where `col2` should be displayed as in the following graph but retaining it's numeric class:

[image: exponent_col2]

Because I want to retain the filtering function in `DT`. However, currently I'm using `sub` and `formatC` to force the column to be displayed in my desired way which makes it character and therefore lost the filtering slider in `DT`.

```r
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- df %>% mutate(col2 = ifelse(col2 <= 10, 
                            formatC(col2, format = "f", digits = 2), 
                            sub("e\\+0?(\\d+)", " x 10<sup>\\1</sup>", formatC(col2, format = "e", digits = 2))))

datatable(df2, escape = F, rownames = FALSE,
  filter = list(position = "top", clear = F, plain = F))
```

This is the slider function that I would like to have:

[image: DT_filter]

Therefore I would like to know how to display the column with exponent while retaining the numeric property (or to retain the `DT` slide-filter function) in an HTML R markdown document.

I'm not sure if it's possible to achieve what I want, so any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the display while keeping the nature of the data is exactly the role of the column option [`render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render).

```r
library(DT)

js <- JS(
  "function(data, type, row, meta) {",
  "  if(type === 'display' && data > 10) {",
  "    let sn = {};",
  "    [sn.coeff, sn.exponent] = data.toExponential().split('e')", 
  "      .map(x => Number(x));",
  "    data = sn.coeff.toFixed(2) + '&times;' + '10<sup>' + sn.exponent + '</sup>';",
  "  }",
  "  return data;",
  "}"
)

df <- data.frame(
  col1 = letters[1:10],
  col2 = c(0, 0.52, 0.93, 2, 10, 51, 523, 52353, 623464, 12356833538)
)

datatable(
  df, 
  options = list(
    columnDefs = list(
      list(targets = 2, render = js)
    )
  )
)
```

[image]